GameObjects fall downwards in Unity when they should MoveTowards spaceship
I'm making my first C# game/program with Unity. Basically, the meteoroids should move towards the spaceship but they lose velocity and start falling downwards. The code below worked before I added the bullets to the game, but now something has gone wrong.
The rest of the game works. I can shoot the meteoroids and they are destroyed. The spaceship relocates after a collision.
I don't think the code is the issue, it's some setting in Unity. Any ideas?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Meteoroid : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private GameObject spaceship;

    [SerializeField] 
    private float speed = 100.0f;

    [SerializeField] 
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Move towards the spaceship's position
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, spaceship.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        // Adjust the rotation to face the spaceship
        transform.up = spaceship.transform.position - transform.position;
    }
}


If you temporarily remove the bullets, will it work again?

That's a lot easier said than done.

This is why version controlling systems are used usually. If you did not use it so far, then unfortunately you will need to do the heavylifting, but it's worth it, as finding out whether it is indeed part of your bullet stuff or something else is crucial in finding out what the cause of the issue is. And of course, start using a VCS from now on and later on these experiments will be a lot more easier.

I do use GitHub and Bitbucket. I just haven't for this. Not yet anyway.

I set gravityScale to Zero on the Rigidbody2D for the Meteoroids. It's fixed.
